# Jpa hibernate sequence pre allocation 

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have been going through the JPA documenation and came across pre allocation thing while assiging sequences id .

Though it is very good for obvious performances reasons.
But I was thinking about the scenario where it can mess up the things.

As I understand ,when we set the allocation size=100 when using table sequencing or sequencing objects as strategy for generating sequences, the persistence provider like hibernate or Eclipse link will maintain the memory counter and the application code for inserting records wont have to go database for each insert.

When that memory counter reaches 100,database sequence is incremented by 100 and same story continues.
All good till now.

But say we get a bug in the production where in we found that records in some of the tables arent being inserted into the DB.

So we prepare the script to insert those records in the DB,now what value we give to the primary keys of the table.If we take the value from the DB,there is a good chance that it will conflict when application tries to insert record using the memory counter and will give SQL exceptions.

Has anybody faced such issue?
And what is the best way to handle such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you use the same strategy as your Hibernate generator in the script. For example, if the sequence is at 2300, and the Hibernate generator increments the sequence by 100 and generates the ID 2301 to 2400 without going to the sequence, do the same in your script.

Or stop the application, run your script, and regenerate the sequence with a value that guarantees that the Hibernate generator won't generate an already used ID.

Comment: Regarding your first approach.My script cannot access the Hibernate memory counter.So if the counter is at 2350.Database is at 2300.in this case what Ids should script use.If it starts using from 2301,it will definetly fail.If it starts from anything after 2350,it will work fine till the application start using the ids using its memory counter and will fail.

Comment: If you know that Hibernate takes slots of 100 IDs, and the database is at 2300, then increment the sequence to 2400 as the Hibernate generator does, and use IDs from 2400 to 2499. When Hibernate doesn't have free IDs in memory, it will go to the database, increment the sequence to 2500, and generate IDs from 2500 to 2599. No conflict.